# Entity Framework code-first defining database name

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 6. I have an `app.config` file in my project and it has a connection string like below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStrDev" 
         connectionString="Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=Dev;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

When I create this database via `enable-migrations` command, EF uses a name for this database like `ConnStrDev`.

But my expectation was using a database name like `Dev` because of the connection string's database name.

My `DbContext` source looks like this

```
public MyDbContext() : base("ConnStrDev")
```

Why does EF use a database name of `ConnStrDev`, instead of `Dev`?

Thank you

Comment: Ensure that your `app.config` file is in your Startup project. E.g. Data project may contain your migrations with config that points to ConnStrDev database, when Web (or any other) project may direct to Dev database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF uses Connection string Name in the `app.config` as DataBase Name.
you can rename Connection string name in config file and `dbcontext`

```
public MyDbContext() : base("dev")


<connectionStrings>
    <add name="dev" 
         connectionString="Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=Dev;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```